# How to check if you can create BigInteger from String

Tags: java

I have a method:

```
public BigInteger method(String param){
    try{
            return new BigInteger(param);
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        LOG.error(e, e);
    }
}
```

I want to check if I can create a `BigInteger` from those `String param` without generating `NumberFormatException`.

Is there any way do it this way?

Comment: Woudln't it be `NumberFormatException` ?

Comment: The problem is to not generate any exception in this case

Comment: Why not? Of course you could try to match against something like `^-?\s*\d+$`, but why not just try and catch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you have 2 possible approaches:

1. You check if the String does only contain numbers, and not more than you could have in a Bigint
2. cast in a `try{}catch()` and catch everything... this is not very performant and more a lazy method of doing it!

[Here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/401142/java/java/check-String-numeric) you can probably find some inspiration :)

Comment: Why is that not very performant? As has been established multiple times on StackOverflow, there _is_ a performance hit, but not a big one. Unless you're in a tight loop, processing millions of strings with a high percentage of invalid ones, you're not going to notice.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [NumberUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/NumberUtils.html) from Apache Commons. it has isDigits() method.

Answer (score 1):

You could check if it matches something like `^-?\s*\d+$`, but just trying and catching is actually fine.

There *is* a performance hit in using exceptions, but it is very, *very* small, so unless you're in a tight loop, looping through millions of strings with a high percentage of invalid strings, just try and catch.
No need to log the error, just return whatever is appropriate for you (either `null` or `BigInteger.ZERO`, I'd imagine).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is perfectly fine to catch the exception here.

Only, logging it is silly. Just return `null` or an appropriate BigInteger [sentinel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value)/default value. (And use the return value appropriately.)